# Environment variables unset on server, using php deployer

Tags: php, deployment, environment-variables

On my local machine I'm using docker to serve my php, I included the .env file using the following lines in my *docker-compose.yml* file, which is working fine, I can see the variables using `getenv()`, the issue is I can't get them to work on my online server.

#### Docker (working locally)

```
app:
  env_file:
    - .env
```

#### Deployer config (not working on server)

I use deployer to deploy my website to my host (which is running nginx and php-fpm), using the following deployer script

```
host('staging')
    ->hostname('app.host.be')
    ->port(22)
    ->stage('staging')
    ->set('deploy_path', '/var/www/')
    ->set('branch', 'master')
    ->identityFile('~/.ssh/id_rsa')
    ->user('admin')
    ->set('env', [
        'MY_ENV' => 'test'
    ]);
```

**I also tried setting the env as outside of the host definition**

```
set('env', [
    'MY_ENV' => 'test'
]);

host('staging')
   ->hostname('app.host.be');
```

But running `getenv()` is only returning the following results on my live server

`array(2) { ["USER"]=> string(8) "www-data" ["HOME"]=> string(8) "/var/www" }`

Answer (score 2):

I would leave a comment, but I don't have enough reputation, yet.

Please take a look at this issue https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/issues/1504

Environment variables in PHP are a bit different, they are not really system level variables, the way docker sets it for example.

So the variables you set with deployer are **available to PHP** for the duration of that run.

Depending on your hosting, you might have enough permissions to modify environment variables on the VM, so you should research a way to modify those. Preferably through a continuous deployment pipeline.

EDIT: please also look into Dotenv in PHP and check out a recommended flow based on that.